# How to find matching variable name for selected option?

Tags: javascript, eval

I have JavaScript function that is triggered on change event. The first step is to check which value user selected. Next is to find matching set of options that will be populated to another select menu. Here is example of my code:

```js
$("#type").on("change", function() {
  var typeVal = $(this).val();

  var approved = [{
    id: 1,
    text: "Month"
  }, {
    id: 2,
    text: "Week"
  }];
  var active = [{
    id: 1,
    text: "Progress"
  }, {
    id: 2,
    text: "No Feedback"
  }, {
    id: 3,
    text: "Office Closed"
  }];
  var inactive = [{
    id: 1,
    text: "Missing"
  }, {
    id: 2,
    text: "Expired"
  }];
  var terminated = [{
    id: 1,
    text: "Natural"
  }, {
    id: 2,
    text: "None"
  }];

  var menuOptions = {
    "1": "approved",
    "2": "active",
    "3": "inactive",
    "4": "terminated",
    "5": "inactive",
    "6": "active"
  };
  
  var getOptions = menuOptions[typeVal];
  console.log(eval(getOptions));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="type" id="type">
  <option value="">Select Type</option>
  <option value="1">Approved</option>
  <option value="2">Active</option>
  <option value="3">Inactive</option>
  <option value="4">Terminated</option>
  <option value="5">Closed</option>
  <option value="6">Pending</option>
</select>
```

My code works so far but I use `eval()` function. I see a lot of posts about that functions and that should be avoided if possible. I'm looking if there is better way to achieve the same goal without that function in javascript? If you have any suggestions please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: (offtopic) don't assign static huge variables inside events. Be flexible and DRY. Put them outside

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Are you suggestion global variable instead of local? Is there specific reason why?

Comment: Exactly (almost). *"global"* but in **scope** - if you know what that means. (Without polluting the `window` scope)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Not sure that I follow up can you write small example?

Comment: Simply wrap your code inside an IIFE or jQuery's DOM ready `jQuery($ => { /*code here and make variables accessible but outside of the change handler */ });`

Comment: just use a switch statement or an object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access variables that exist on a certain context much like you access an array or object key.

If you have the variables inside your `onchange` callback function, you can change `window[getOptions]` to `this[getOptions]`.

```js
$("#type").on("change", function() {
  var typeVal = $(this).val();
  
  var getOptions = menuOptions[typeVal];
  console.log(window[getOptions]);
});


var menuOptions = {
  "1": "approved",
  "2": "active",
  "3": "inactive",
  "4": "terminated",
  "5": "inactive",
  "6": "active"
};

var approved = [{
  id: 1,
  text: "Month"
}, {
  id: 2,
  text: "Week"
}];
var active = [{
  id: 1,
  text: "Progress"
}, {
  id: 2,
  text: "No Feedback"
}, {
  id: 3,
  text: "Office Closed"
}];
var inactive = [{
  id: 1,
  text: "Missing"
}, {
  id: 2,
  text: "Expired"
}];
var terminated = [{
  id: 1,
  text: "Natural"
}, {
  id: 2,
  text: "None"
}];
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="type" id="type">
  <option value="">Select Type</option>
  <option value="1">Approved</option>
  <option value="2">Active</option>
  <option value="3">Inactive</option>
  <option value="4">Terminated</option>
  <option value="5">Closed</option>
  <option value="6">Pending</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code:

```
console.log(Object.entries(menuOptions).filter(([a, b]) => a == typeVal)[0][1]);
```